# ¿COMO PUEDO ELIMINAR UNA COLUMNA DE UN GRIDVIEW?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Estoy tratando de eliminar una columna de un gridview en ASP.NET y VB.NET lo he tratado de hacer de esta forma con el gridview1.columns(0).visible = false y me sale el error de que El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.

este es mi código

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CARGAR_GRID()
End Sub
Private Sub CARGAR_GRID()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    OpenConex()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIO"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sql, CONEX)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim registro As New DataTable
    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = True
    'GridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False 'ELIINAR FILA EN BLANCO DATAGRID
    CloseConex()
End Sub
```

se los agradecería si me podrían ayudar

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mas alla de mostrarla o no, la necesitas para algo?